# Logs extraños y sin control en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, logcat

estoy creando una aplicación para android en android estudio. pero desde hace algunos días me salen unos logs extraños que antes no me salían y no sé cómo desactivarlos o hacer para que no salgan.

Los logs incluyen intentos de conexión a wifi, acceso a archivos y acceder a la ubicación, entre otros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un ejemplo de los logs que me salen y ninguno proviene de mi paquete de app
Estoy usando kotlin

¿Podría alguien decirme por qué me salen esos logs?
¿de alguna forma infecté mi app de algún virus?
¿alguna actividad está haciendo que todo eso me salga?

Comment: Normalmente el visor de logs de android studio te permite filtrar logs por paquete, habrás cambiado el filtro para que incluya todos los logs del dispositivo? Porque es posible verlos, y tiene pinta de ser lo que está pasando aquí. No es un virus, simplemente estás viendo todos los logs que genera el dispositivo, en general.

Comment: Sí, al parecer es así. Muhas gracias

Comment: Define inicialmente como filtro : package:<nombre de package name>

Answer (score 0):

En versiones anteriores de Android Studio `Flamingo` podrías filtrar de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las versiones actuales, puedes filtrar por:

```
`tag`: Coincide con el campo tag de la entrada de registro.
`package`: Coincide con el nombre del paquete de la app de registro.
`process`: Coincide con el nombre del proceso de la app de registro.
`message`: Coincide con la parte del mensaje de la entrada de registro.
`level`: Coincide con el nivel de registro grave especificado o con uno más alto, por ejemplo, DEBUG.
`age`: Coincide si la marca de tiempo de la entrada es reciente. Los valores se especifican como un número seguido de una letra que denota la unidad de tiempo: s para segundos, m para minutos, h para horas y d para días. Por ejemplo, age: 5m filtra solo los mensajes que se registraron en los últimos 5 minutos.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Me parece que tu problema es simplemente que no configuras correctamente el filtro, inicia por definir el "package name" de tu app**, para ver únicamente su información relacionada, puedes relizarlo definiendo en el filtro:

```
package:<nombre de package name>
```

Es importante revisar:

[**Cómo ver registros con Logcat**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat?hl=es-419)